# Is there a beforesend Javascript promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am using a script to send data to google drive. The script has two functions to detect when the request was sent or not. Is there a function alternative to jquery beforesend?

To detect that the request is being sending?

```
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})  
         .then((response) => {
               alertify.success("Sent succesfully");
            })
             .catch((err) => {
                alertify.error("Failed to send");
            });
```

Comment: Just wrap every call to your fetch function in firing a `beforesend` event?

Comment: sorry i don't understand how to do this.

Comment: See the second example in baao's answer

Comment: Now it's the only one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there's not, but you can wrap it in your own function that you use everywhere.

```
function myFetch() {
    console.log('about to send');
    return fetch.apply(this, arguments);
}

 myFetch('/echo').then(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: I would not recommend to overwrite the global `fetch` variable, but rather just wrap in a custom function that you use everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @bergi, makes sense. I've added that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to have hooks on calls to `window.fetch`. You could create a minimal wrapper class that executes that call for you, and allow you to pass *before-send* hooks to it that it will execute in advance:

```js
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation:
//-----------------------------------------------------------

class CustomFetch {

    constructor(url, init = {}) {
        this.url = url;
        this.init = init;
        this.promise = null;
        this.beforeSends = [];
    }

    /**
     * Runs the actual fetch call.
     * @return {Promise<Response>}
     */
    fetch() {
        this._runBeforeSends();
        this.promise = fetch(this.url, this.init);
        return this.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Runs all registered before-send functions
     */
    _runBeforeSends() {
        this.beforeSends.forEach(fn => fn(this));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Register a beforesend handler.
     * @param {function(url, init): void} fn
     */
    beforeSend(fn) {
        this.beforeSends.push(fn);
        return this;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Usage example:
//-----------------------------------------------------------

// Create a special fetch wrapper with pre-defined arguments for 'Actual fetch':
const postFetch = new CustomFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');

// Register a before-send handler:
postFetch.beforeSend((fetch) => {
  console.log(`About to send to ${fetch.url}`);
});
  

// call the fetch() method and get back the Promise<Response>
// of the native fetch call:
const posP = postFetch.fetch();

// When loaded, log the response data
posP.then((res) => res.json()).then(console.log);
```

This is a little more verbose than a simple function wrapper, but also gives you the advantage of being able to re-use a `CustomFetch` instance – you can keep calling `someFetch.fetch()`, and it will in turn keep calling the registered before-send handlers before proceeding with calling `window.fetch`.