# beforeSend: function() in fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am currently migrating the use of `ajax` to the `fetch`, however I am needing a parameter/function the Ajax native `beforeSend: function()`. I would like to perform the same action without requiring an implementation in fetch (*a creation of a new class for example*)

jQuery `$.ajax` structure:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'post',
    data: {...},
    beforeSend: function() {
        // perform the action..
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        // receive response data
    }
});
```

JavaScript `fetch` structure:

```
fetch('...').then((response) => {
    return response.text();
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

How do I determine such a function without needing an implementation or creating a new class on fetch. Is there any means or only implementation? because of my searches I only found implementations like `CustomFetch` ([Is there a beforesend Javascript promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704104/is-there-a-beforesend-javascript-promise)) and others.

Comment: What does your `beforeSend` method logic looks like?

Comment: @MinusFour As well? for the current application?

Comment: Yes, how do you actually use it. jQuery basically uses this method to access a version of a XHR object. The interface is very different with `fetch`.

Comment: So do you think I should handle the actions before the end with XHR object?

Comment: No, there's no XHR object with `fetch`. It's a different interface. Whatever you did with the XHR object inside `beforeSend` will most likely have a different way to do so with `fetch`.

Comment: @MinusFour solved problem! this example as first my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solved problem!

No need to implement and/or create a new `fetch` class. Using only parameters as *"function inside function"*. I hope you can help others!

```js
function ipGetAddress(format) {
  requestFetch = function() {
    // perform the action..
    console.log('** beforeSend request fetch **');
    return fetch.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  requestFetch(`https://api.ipify.org?format=${format}`).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data.ip);
  });
}

ipGetAddress('json') // return local ip address..
```